# undefined reference to self-written function

Tags: c++, codeblocks, undefined-reference

I know it has to be a dumb question, but I can't solve this problem for 5 hours now and it's killing me: I'm learning C++ and doing everything as I was told to, but I can't build my function, because the compiler just wouldn't recognize my function. I tried using an absolutely simple one, but the problem remains. I'm using Code Blocks. The main.cpp, ezmukszik.cpp and ezmukszik.h are in the same project library and I checked in Settings/Compiler/Build Options to explicitly add the working directory to the compiler search dirs. The error message is the following:

```
in function main
/in line 8/ undefined reference to 'ezmukszik()'
```

The header:

```
#ifndef EZMUKSZIK_H_INCLUDED
#define EZMUKSZIK_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

int ezmukszik();

#endif // EZMUKSZIK_H_INCLUDED
```

The source code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int ezmukszik()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "D:\BME suli\C++\Programok\ezmukszik\ezmukszik.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ezmukszik();
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure "ezmukszik.cpp" is under "sources" and not "headers". It looks like it's somehow not being passed to the linker.

Comment: the backslash in the include file is an escape char. Forward slash / should work as well as \\

Comment: Unfortunately it is under sources.

Comment: The problem remained the same with either / or \\ as well.

Comment: Your `ezmukszik.cpp` should probably include `ezmukszik.h`

Comment: some unrelated comments: don't include iostream in the header since it is not needed there, include the "ezmukszik.h" header in ezmukszik.cpp. dont use `using namespace std` in the global scope also when you include the "ezmukszik.h" dont use an absolute path like that, instead add the include path in the make file or whatever build environment you use.

Comment: Are you sure you are linking the source file correctly?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9910af6862a7ee8).

Comment: I've included ezmukszik.h in ezmukszik.cpp, no change. tried not to use namespace (though according to Accelerated c++ it would be quite ok), no change. tried with simple #include "ezmukszik.h" without the path, nothing changed (i've already written that i set the build the include the current file's director in the search path).

Comment: So  ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ you say it has to do sg with my CodeBlocks build? I'll try to reinstall then.

Comment: Reinstalled it, the problem remains.

Comment: Your (fixed from comment suggestions) code also works on Visual Studio, so I also think it's your build system. Try using CMake to generate a project. It works with CodeBlocks. I'll post an answer explaining how to do it if you're interested.

Comment: I am very much interested, thank you for the help. I've downloaded Cmake and tried to generate a project, it asks for a Cmakelists.txt or sg like that. Could you help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem, it was an annoying solution: I added the source file in Code Blocks from the new file window, and it was displayed under the project sources, but for some reason it still didn't compiled. Adding it with a right click in the rightmost window solved the problem.:)
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The error is a LINKER error and means your `ezmukszik.cpp` file is not linked together with the `main.o` after being compiled to `ezmukszik.o`.

Check the linking command line.

Comment: I'm sorry for being such a noob, but could you tell me how do I do that?

Comment: Simplest way is to try linking your app from the command line e.g. `g++ -o myapp main.cpp ezmukszik.cpp`. If that works correctly then open CodeBlocks project settings and find Linker settings. CodeBlocks wiki has a whole page on diagnosing such errors: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_(errors)

Comment: It says it doesn't recognize g++ as a command or program (I have Windows 7 64), should I download it separetly from Code Blocks?

Comment: It should be already included with code blocks, just find it using search. (It's apparently not added to PATH)